# in repeated string finding the total number of time the occurrence of any character

Tags: java, arrays

Given an integer,n, find and print the number of letter a's in the first n  letters of infinite string.

For example, if the string s='abcac' and n=10, the substring we consider is abcacabcac , the first 10 characters of her infinite string. There are 4 occurrences of a in the substring.

```
static long repeatedString(String s, long n) {
        long len = s.length(), count = 0;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
        char[] c = s.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            sb.append(c[(i % len)]);
            if (sb.charAt(i) == 'a')
                count++;
        }
        return count;
    }
```

it is showing error

> incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from long to int
>   sb.append(c[i%len]);

if i am type casting the len then it is not passing the test case for the value whose length is greater than 10^9 for example if my input is

> a
>   1000000000000

then the output must be 1000000000000

> note-> for any given input i have to calculate the total number of 'a'
>   present in that given string

EDIT:i am calling my function as

> long result = repeatedString("a", 1000000000000);

Comment: `sb.append(c[(int) (i%len)]);`

Comment: already tried and o/p is error only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a StringBuilder.  
Get the result you want by iterating the initial string and multiply it as many times as needed, meaning by `(n / len)`, then add what is left by the division:

```
static long repeatedString(String s, long n) {
    long len = s.length();

    if (len == 0)
        return 0;

    long rep = n / len;
    long count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (s.charAt(i) == 'a')
            count++;
    }

    count *= rep;

    long rest = n % len;

    for (int i = 0; i < rest; i++) {
        if (s.charAt(i) == 'a')
            count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Correct solution, but **you do not have to iterate over the string TWICE**.

Comment: Right, the 2nd time for the substring.

Comment: Yes, I see. This is unnecessary. You can move it to the first loop. What if `n = str.length() - 1` and `n = 1_000_000`.

Comment: If I do, I will have an extra `if` to maintain. Plus isn't this clearer?

Comment: Look at my solution, a put before yours. We have same approach, by mo solution is much simplier.

Comment: what if i wanna use stringbuilder what changing i have to made for that

Comment: @RAVIKUMARSHARMACSE16 you don't need it. You only use StringBuilder when you want to construct large strings by repeated appending. You don;t need this to solve this problem.

Comment: all test case is passing but the test case whose n value is greater than 10^8(10 to the power 8) is only failing

Comment: @RAVIKUMARSHARMACSE16 are you talking about your code or mine?

Comment: It because you build a very lager `String`. You should avoid it.

Comment: @RAVIKUMARSHARMACSE16 you chose a method that is inefficient. The solution is simpler.

Comment: @oleg.cherednik that's what i have done, for lager string i have taken stringbuilder as forpas  suggested then where is the fault

Comment: @RAVIKUMARSHARMACSE16 I did not propose StringBuilder for any case in this problem.

Comment: @RAVIKUMARSHARMACSE16 Then do look at implementation of `StringBuilder` and open your eyes about it!

Comment: @forpas i will correct myself thats not a big issue.i will try your solution

Comment: @forpas actually i have used stringbuilder as you told that you can use it when there is formation of stringbuilder

Comment: @RAVIKUMARSHARMACSE16 You used StringBuilder to construct a very large string. You don't need this in this problem. There is a simpler solution.

Answer (score 1):

Part of your question seemed a bit vague, but from the last line, I get that, you want to find number of occurrences of a particular character in a string.

You can use a `HashMap` to add the unique characters of your String and set the value as the number of occurrences of the character.

What I am saying, looks something like this in code:

```java
HashMap<Character,Integer> hm = new HashMap<Character,Integer>();

char[] str = s.toCharArray();

for(char c : str) {

    if(hm.containsKey(c))
        hm.put(c, hm.get(c)+1);

    else
        hm.put(c, 1);
}
```

Now you can just choose the character of your choice in the string to get it's number of occurrences, like this:

```java
if(hm.get(character)!=null)
    ans = hm.get(character);

else
    ans = 0;
```

There is also a library, I am making [for this here.](https://github.com/Pradyuman7/Algorithmics)

**Edit:**

From the edit, the question is much more clear, for that all you need to do is to add the characters of your string to the previous string, until the length is met.

After that, you can use the new string like in the code, I've given here.

Comment: `char[] str = s.toCharArray();` creates extra char array in the memory. According this case, `s.charAt(i)` is much better to iterate over characters.

Answer (score 0):

I think you do not have to use `StringBuidler` (moreover, for big `n`, this could flow `OutOfMemoryError`), but count required letters on the fly.

```
public static long repeatedString(String str, long n, char ch) {
    long count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        if (str.charAt(i) == ch)
            continue;

        count += n / str.length();
        count += i < n % str.length() ? 1 : 0;
    }

    return count;
}
```